# More ruby way to count objects that match criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here is what I am doing now:

```
def get_counts
  products = Product.all
  a_count, b_count, c_count = 0, 0, 0
  products.collect{ |p| a_count+=1 if p.some_attribute == 'a' }
  products.collect{ |p| b_count+=1 if p.some_attribute == 'b' }
  products.collect{ |p| c_count+=1 if p.some_attribute == 'c' }
  return a_count, b_count, c_count
end
```

This feels horribly scripty to me.  I tried using inject but couldn't get it to work how I wanted. Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve on @xdazz's answer

```
def get_counts
  Product.where(some_attribute: ['a','b','c']).
          count(group: "some_attribute")
end
```

This will return a hash in the form:

```
{'a' => 3, 'b' => 4, 'c' => 5}
```

Comment: ActiveRecord uses `IN` automatically when an array is passed: `Product.where(some_attribute: ['a','b','c'])`

Comment: `return` looks so unidiomatic in Ruby... it confuses more than it helps when it's the last expression. Note that you can also write: `where(:some_attribute => ["a", "b", "c"])`.

Comment: Duly noted and updated.  @Stefan, I wasn't aware that the `IN` operator had been built in to ActiveRecord, this wasn't the case in Rails 2.3 - thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_counts
  return Product.where(:some_attribute => 'a').count, Product.where(:some_attribute => 'b').count, Product.where(:some_attribute => 'c').count
end
```

If you want only one query, then use group by.

Comment: Definitely more concise, but isn't this running the query 3 times now?

Comment: @Josh If you want only one query, could use group by .